# What are the implications of calling NumPy's C API functions from multiple threads?

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api, gil

This is risky business, and I understand the Global Interpreter Lock to be a formidable foe of parallelism. However, if I'm using [NumPy's C API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html) (specifically the `PyArray_DATA` macro on a NumPy array), are there potential consequences to invoking it from multiple concurrent threads?

Note that I will still own the GIL and not be releasing it with [NumPy's threading support](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#threading-support). Also, even if NumPy makes no guarantees about thread safety but `PyArray_DATA` is thread-safe in practice, **that's good enough for me**.

I'm running Python 2.6.6 with NumPy 1.3.0 on Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question here, but after poking into the source code for NumPy 1.3.0, I believe the answer is: **Yes, `PyArray_DATA` is thread-safe.**

1. `PyArray_DATA` is defined in
   ndarrayobject.h:

   ```
   #define PyArray_DATA(obj) ((void *)(((PyArrayObject *)(obj))->data))
   ```
2. The PyArrayObject struct type is
   defined in the same file; the field
   of interest is:

   ```
   char *data;
   ```

   So now, the question is whether accessing `data` from multiple threads is safe or not.
3. Creating a new NumPy array from scratch (i.e., not deriving it from an existing data structure) passes a `NULL` data pointer to `PyArray_NewFromDescr`, defined in arrayobject.c.
4. This causes `PyArray_NewFromDescr` to invoke `PyDataMem_NEW` in order to allocate memory for the PyArrayObject's `data` field. This is simply a macro for malloc:

   ```
   #define PyDataMem_NEW(size) ((char *)malloc(size))
   ```

In summary, `PyArray_DATA` is thread-safe and as long as the NumPy arrays are created separately, it is safe to write to them from different threads.